# Extend one list of key-value pairs with another one

Tags: erlang

I have two lists of key-value pairs (`[{key_1, value_1}, ..., {key_n, value_n}]`). What is the best method of updating first list with the second one? For example:

```
1> extend([{1, "one"}, {2, "too"}], [{2, "two"}, {3, "three"}]).
[{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}]
```

I've found just two similar function: `lists:keystore/4`, which updates a single tuple, and `lists:keymerge`, which merges two lists without removing key duplicates.

Comment: But if you have (for instance) [{1,"one"},{2."two"}] and [{1,"odin"}] (means the same keys have different values) , what result you are going to get?

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus, `[{1, "odin"}, {2, "two"}]`. In my case each key should have a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer myself. Erlang's `orddict` module deals with pure sorted list of `{key, value}` pairs. So, `extend` function can be defined as follows:

```
extend(L1, L2) ->
    orddict:merge(fun(_Key, _V1, V2) -> V2 end, L1, L2).
```

If `L1` and `L2` aren't initially sorted, then they can be transformed to orddicts with `orddict:from_list/1`.

Comment: `orddict:merge/3`'s solution is elegant and most concise, which is good for maintenance. Typical good Erlang code IMHO. In terms of algorithmic complexity, a recursive function could avoid the initial sorting of at least one of the lists. If you are dealing with large lists, you'd better use gb_trees anyway.

Answer (score 0):

for instance

```
extend(L1,L2) -> 
    lists:foldl(fun({K,V},Acc) -> lists:keystore(K,1,Acc,{K,V}) end, L1,L2).
```

or

```
extend(L1,L2) ->
    compact(lists:keysort(1,L1++L2),[]).

compact([],Acc) -> lists:reverse(Acc);
compact([{K,_},{K,V}| Rest], Acc) -> compact([{K,V} |Rest],Acc);
compact([X|Rest],Acc) -> compact(Rest,[X|Acc]).
```

Comment: Unfortunately, both of these methods will have greater time complexity, then `orddict:merge`.

Comment: I don think so. But let we try. https://gist.github.com/odobenus/6793184#file-gistfile1-erl , and then for instance  so:test(fun so:e0/2, 10000). (compact version) gives 3615 , so:test(fun so:e2/2, 10000). (keystore) gives 1353430, and your version so:test(fun so:e2/2, 10000). (orddict) gives 1775789 microsecs.  So.. compact version looks like the best.

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus the reason why your compact version is faster is mostly because of `orddict:from_list/1` which has O(n^2) complexity while your `lists:keysort(1, L1++L2)` has O(nlog_n) complexity. It's completely unrelated to `orddict:merge/3`. Indeed, `compact/2` itself is of O(n) (+ the reverse operation), just like `orddict:merge/3` (which has greater space complexity, though, as it is not tail-recursive). If you replace the two calls to `orddict:from_list/1` with `lists:keysort/2`, you'll get (on average) slightly better times than the compact version as you're sorting n+m with compact.